# how to insert multi - multiple selected values in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want insert multi - multiple selected list into db , But unfortunately it can't.

```js
`javascript`

<script>
var i = 1;

$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});

function addRow() {
  var maxField = 5; //Input fields increment limitation
  var tr ='<tr>'+
         '<td><div><select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="exs[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:500px;"><option value="3">Laravel</option><option value="4">Laravel ACL</option><option value="5">Laravel PDF</option></select></div>'+ i +'.</td>'+'</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
  i++;
};
</script>
<script>
 //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < maxField){ 
            i++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        }
    });

</script>
```

```html
`html`





<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>No.</th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a href='#' class="addRow">Add Row</a></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
php

$limit = count($_POST['exs']);
for ($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++)
{
$exs_string[$i] =implode('.', $_POST['exs']);
$sql= "INSERT INTO exe (exstring)  VALUES ('{$exs_string[$i]}');
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

result in db :
[result in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRgLf.png)

Each iteration is stored in a string

Comment: And php code is where?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through POST array for database insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302808/loop-through-post-array-for-database-insert)